# DAX to multiply two measures and the summarize the total

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, multiplication, summarization

I am fairly new to Power BI and was hoping to solve my total (multiplication problem).

I have running inventory table for supplies ordered. I need to have a breakdown of the cost of those supplies based on the last item ordered(prices constantly change). I have two measures, one for the latest cost, and the second for the latest units used.

```
Latest Unit/Cost =
VAR maxdate =
    MAX ( InventoryJ[Date Ordered] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( InventoryJ[Cost/Unit] ), InventoryJ[Date Ordered] = maxdate )
```

and

```
Latest UnitsUsed =
VAR maxdate =
    MAX ( InventoryJ[Date Ordered] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( InventoryJ[Unit Used] ), InventoryJ[Date Ordered] = maxdate )
```

In my matrix they work great, even though the total is incorrect in the table.

[Matrix table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKex1.png)

Now I am stuck on multiplying these two measures together for the latest units used and the latest cost per unit and then summarizing the total for the values.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table looks like this

### Table

| Items | Unit Cost | Unit Used | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | 4.25 | 16 | 03 November 2021 |
| Item 1 | 3.44 | 20 | 03 December 2021 |
| Item 1 | 3.93 | 48 | 13 March 2021 |
| Item 1 | 7.57 | 32 | 14 March 2021 |
| Item 1 | 2.45 | 33 | 15 March 2021 |
| Item 1 | 7.32 | 34 | 16 March 2021 |
| Item 1 | 3.34 | 33 | 17 March 2021 |
| Item 1 | 9.17 | 26 | 18 March 2021 |
| Item 1 | 9.59 | 25 | 19 March 2021 |
| Item2 | 4.1 | 27 | 03 November 2021 |
| Item2 | 1.74 | 47 | 03 December 2021 |
| Item2 | 8.08 | 19 | 13 March 2021 |
| Item2 | 7.52 | 13 | 14 March 2021 |
| Item2 | 6.7 | 49 | 15 March 2021 |
| Item2 | 4.24 | 13 | 16 March 2021 |
| Item2 | 0.95 | 40 | 17 March 2021 |
| Item2 | 0.37 | 19 | 18 March 2021 |
| Item2 | 9.77 | 38 | 19 March 2021 |

### Calculation

You can use `SUMX` and `LASTDATE` to get the last `Unit Cost` multiplied by `Unit Used`.

```
Cost =
CALCULATE (
    SUMX ( 'Table', [Unit Cost] * [Unit Used] ),
    LASTDATE ( 'Table'[Date] )
)
```

### Output

[image]